# round down function using floor(c++)

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, function, floor

I want to make a simple function that rounds down a double into integer with one condition. If it rounds down to zero, I want it to return 1.

This is what I made.

```
int Round(double number)
{
    int result;
    result=floor(number);
    if(result=0){result=1;}
    return result;
}
```

But somehow it always returns 0... Any idea whats wrong with my code?

Its done with c++ in visual studio 2010.

Comment: turn on all warnings, you'll see what's wrong with your code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`=` is used for assignment. Use `==` for comparison:

```
if(result==0){result=1;}
```

Answer (score 2):

`result = 0` will assign its value to `0`. You want `==` instead.